# python, find waiting time until next occurrence for continuous value time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a pandas time series (or numpy array or a simple python list, if easier), I want, for each point in the series, find the waiting time until next time the series is at this level. So if day T is 0 and day T+1 is positive, I want to find the number of days to wait until the series is 0 or below. If day T+1 is negative, find waiting time until the series is 0 or above

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234567)
N = 10
ts = pd.util.testing.makeTimeSeries(N).cumsum()
```

I can do it with double loop

```
def min2(x):
    return min(x) if len(x) > 0 else np.nan

out = ts*np.nan
for idx, (d,v) in enumerate(ts.iteritems()):
    if idx+1 < N:
        if ts[idx+1] > ts[idx]:
            out[d] = min2([k for k in xrange(idx+2, N) if ts[k] <= ts[idx]]) - idx
        elif ts[idx+1] < ts[idx]:
            out[d] = min2([k for k in xrange(idx+2, N) if ts[k] >= ts[idx]]) - idx
        else:
            out[d] = 1

print ts

2000-01-03   -0.514625
2000-01-04   -0.964179
2000-01-05    0.770442
2000-01-06    1.413822
2000-01-07    1.439962
2000-01-10    1.520343
2000-01-11    0.722954
2000-01-12    0.094867
2000-01-13   -0.251360
2000-01-14    0.716725
Freq: B, dtype: float64

print out

2000-01-03    2.0
2000-01-04    NaN
2000-01-05    4.0
2000-01-06    3.0
2000-01-07    2.0
2000-01-10    NaN
2000-01-11    NaN
2000-01-12    2.0
2000-01-13    NaN
2000-01-14    NaN
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

But is there an efficient way (for large N)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using two stacks. It's unfortunately very hard to vectorise. Nonetheless, in my 10,000 sample test it runs several 100-fold faster than the original loop:

```
import numpy as np

freqs = np.random.randn(20)/10
N = 10**4
data = np.sin(np.arange(N)[:, None] * freqs).sum(axis=-1)

test = False
if test:
    data = """
    2000-01-03   -0.514625
    2000-01-04   -0.964179
    2000-01-05    0.770442
    2000-01-06    1.413822
    2000-01-07    1.439962
    2000-01-10    1.520343
    2000-01-11    0.722954
    2000-01-12    0.094867
    2000-01-13   -0.251360
    2000-01-14    0.716725
    """
    data = np.array([float(d.strip().split()[1])
                     for d in data.strip().split('\n')])

def min2(x):
    return min(x) if len(x) > 0 else np.nan

def OP(data):
    out = data*np.nan
    for idx, v in enumerate(data):
        if idx+1 < N:
            if data[idx+1] > data[idx]:
                out[idx] = min2([k for k in xrange(idx+2, N) if data[k] <= data[idx]]) - idx
            elif data[idx+1] < data[idx]:
                out[idx] = min2([k for k in xrange(idx+2, N) if data[k] >= data[idx]]) - idx
            else:
                out[idx] = 1
    return out

def PP(data):
    stack = np.empty(data.shape, int)
    wait = np.zeros(data.shape) + np.nan
    lp = 0
    hp = -1
    dd = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(data, (data.size-1, 2),
                                         2 * data.strides)
    for j, (do, dn) in enumerate(dd):
        if dn > do:
            stack[lp] = j
            lp += 1
            while hp < -1 and dn >= data[stack[hp+1]]:
                hp += 1
                wait[stack[hp]] = j - stack[hp] + 1
        elif dn < do:
            stack[hp] = j
            hp -= 1
            while lp > 0 and dn <= data[stack[lp-1]]:
                lp -= 1
                wait[stack[lp]] = j - stack[lp] + 1
        else:
            wait[j] = 1
    return wait

def check(data, wait):
    w = np.where(~np.isnan(wait))[0]
    assert np.all((data[w + 1] - data[w])
                  * (data[w + wait[w].astype(int)] - data[w]) <= 0)
    assert np.all((data[w+1] - data[w])
                  * (data[w + wait[w].astype(int) - 1] - data[w]) >= 0)
    print('test passed')

waito = OP(data)
wait = PP(data)
check(data, wait)
print('outputs equal',
      np.all((wait==waito) | (np.isnan(wait) & np.isnan(waito))))

from timeit import timeit

print('\nTimings:')
for f in OP, PP:
    print('{:16s} {:10.6f} ms'.format(f.__name__, timeit(
        lambda: f(data), number=10) * 100))
```

Sample output:

```
test passed
('outputs equal', True)

Timings:
OP               12099.189901 ms
PP                26.705098 ms
```